# IntelliJ doesn't recognize dependencies downloaded via Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, retrofit2

I'm having a problem importing dependencies into my code in IntelliJ
My build.gradle file is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Gradle doesn't seem to struggle to find and download the dependencies as I can find them locally in

> C:\Users%USER%.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.retrofit2\retrofit\2.9.0

I've updated IntelliJ to make sure it's up-to-date and have also tried invalidating cache and restarting several times. I'm out of ideas at this point, any help would be kind.

Comment: `problem importing dependencies into my code in IntelliJ` what exactly is the problem?

Comment: When manually importing classes, it doesn't recognize the packages, show in this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/W1UApjI.png

It also doesn't auto-suggest the correct package to import when referencing Classes within Retrofit. This works flawlessly on Android Studio so i'm not sure why i'm struggling here

Comment: Will Gradle compile the project is you build it with such a class specified? Does Gradle Reload action from Gradle tool window complete successfully? Any errors in  idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action)? make sure you do not have Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Generate .iml files for modules imported from Gradle** option enabled and call a **Reload** action in Gradle tool window. It must complete successfully for the IDE to download and set up the dependencies. Provide a sample project if problem remains.